# Swift view controller test fails with EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION when accessing the view property

Tags: ios, swift, testing

We're trying to set up tests for our view controllers, and we've successfully done so with some of our more simple view controllers. But we just started getting an `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)` with one of our more complex view controllers. Our test looks like this:

```
class GEKMasterViewControllerTest: XCTestCase {

    var viewController: GEKMasterViewController!

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()

        viewController = GEKMasterViewController()
        let _ = viewController.view
    }
}
```

And it always fails on this line in the actual view controller:

```
override public func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Set the main view height
    mainViewHeight = self.view.frame.height - 64.0 // EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
```

All classes are set as `public` and the app target is correctly imported in the test files. When you comment this line out, it proceeds to hit several other lines in the view controller and fail. It seems as though there is a more serious issue with the way we have our tests setup that causes this behavior, but all the (scarce) Swift testing resources show similar usage. Is there a common reason we would see an `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION` when trying to access the view property of a view controller in a Swift test target?

Comment: Did you check to se whether `self.view` is nil? When initializing a view controller, you should do it through a storyboard, which initializes all of the outlets and the view controller's `view`.

Comment: Actually I think we tracked down the issue and it was related to IBOutlets. We're going to dig deeper and I'll answer my own question with the details.